# Chrome loses Compose sequences whose last character uses Shift

Tags: x11, chrome, input-method, compose-key

In Chrome 35.0.1916.153 or 36.0.1985.125, sometimes, my <kbd>Compose</kbd> key partially doesn't work. As far as I can tell, combinations whose last character uses the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key that don't work. For example, `'e`→`é` and `/=`→`≠` work but not `'E`→`É` or `->`→`→`. In this post, when I say that a combination doesn't work, I mean that nothing happens when I press it; for example, pressing <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> inserts `ab`.

In my running instance, if I type <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>, this inserts the character `é`, as it should be. But if I type <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, nothing happens. The same goes in an incognito window that I already have open. However, if I open a new incognito window in that instance, <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> inserts `É` as it should at first, but as soon as I open a web page, combinations ending in a shifted key stop working. The same goes with another user account with a fresh profile: `'E`→`É` only works until I load a web page.

This problem didn't start today. I don't remember if it started when I upgraded from Chrome 34.x (stable) to Chrome 35.x (stable), but it started around that time.

I normally have the environment variable `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim`, because I don't want Gtk applications to use an input method different from standard X applications. Removing this variable for Chrome seems to make <kbd>Compose</kbd> work normally.

What is the effect of `GTK_IM_MODULE` on Chrome? How do I get it to reliably use the X11 input method?

Comment: I have 38.x version, and these combinations works fine. You have to try to set the `xim` with the `im-config` application. [I had `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` as well with some other options](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166954/59928), and it worked wrong. I guess the `im-config` sets some variable besides these ones.

Comment: I haven't seen this bug for a while, since I upgraded to Chrome 38 I think. I'm going to guess that this was a bug introduced in Chrome 35 and fixed in 37 or 38.

Comment: This still doesn't work here, in version 87.0.4280.60 (Official Build) beta (64-bit).

I did try unsetting all GTK_* environment variables but it made no difference.

I created a but in Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1149145