# Some apps doesn't accept some characters from the «Compose» key

Tags: x11, kde, character-encoding, compose-key

The problem is that the compose key works fine, but some application doesn't accept some characters from it. E.g. I can type the character `∞` in Emacs (<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>), but this won't work in FireFox, Konsole and Kate. But many other characters, e.g. `€` typed there *(in FireFox, Konsole and Kate)* with *Compose* work just fine. Also I may insert a *problem symbols* with a simple copy-paste *(from any of two clipboards)*.

So, what could cause it, and how to fix it?

Sorry, but I have no idea how to research the issue. I found people whose Compose key didn't worked at all in some apps, but in my case it is works, though somehow partially.

**Setup:** the compose key bound to the right Super key in both `/etc/default/keyboard` and KDE keyboard settings.

Comment: Usually it's because different toolkits (Athena, Motif, Gtk, KDE, …) use different input methods. What does `env | grep IM` show? Do you have an input method configured anywhere?

Comment: @Gilles [here it is](http://pastebin.com/vfjh8SqC).

Comment: @Gilles I didn't knew about a different input methods… So, do I have to install ibus to fix it? Also I am wondering wouldn't it conflict with KDE keyboard settings? As I remember, the ibus have its own settings too.

Comment: @Gilles well, I remember I tried ibus, and it seemed to me raw. I couldn't find how to stop the daemon *(it isn't present in `/etc/init.d/` and in list of KDE's services)*, the only way I found was to purge it. Also I just installed it again, and found that it don't even have a setting to have a different layouts by a windows. Are there a way to use the native KDE input method for all applications?

Comment: I found two interesting details. The first is that even for «ibus» isn't installed, I have the package «ibus-qt4». And it have the file `ibqtim-ibus.so`, lsof of which shows that it is being used by a KDE apps. The second appeared from [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300345/compose-key-combinations-are-wrong-in-kde-qt-apps): for I press «Compose+a+_», it gives the `ā` in Emacs, and the `ª` FireFox, and etc. I guess I have to try to remove this package, and see does it fix the problem.

Comment: Hmmm… I found even two packages with ibus-qt in the name, and purged the both. Now I restarted X, but the problem is still present.

Comment: That's just crazy! I added to my `.xsession` the three lines `export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export XMODIFIERS=@im=xim
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim`, restarted X, and now Compose key refused to work at all in FireFox and Konsole!But it is still works in Emacs and Chrome! I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Gilles, I found an answer. So, the problem was with different Input Methods, used by different applications; and IMs in turn use different Compose files — ones used by X are  `/usr/share/X11/locale/<your-locale>/Compose` and `~/.XCompose` *(the last isn't present by default, but you may create it for custom combinations)*, and the one used by Qt is in… Well, looks like nobody knows.

The solution is to set `xim` to be used as default input method by all applications. You can call `im-config`, and choose there *xim* as the default input method, or you can manually edit `/etc/profile` file to add these lines:

```bsh
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export XMODIFIERS=@im=xim
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim
```

Not sure about `im-config`, but for the way with `/etc/profile` reboot will be needed.

Comment: Also I found that `im-config` in some cases instead of saving a new configuration falls with a GTK error. I guess this a feature because for this case the application have a flag `-c` → it launches a terminal UI 

Comment: I have fixed your grammar, as the answer was had to read. Can you check that I have not changed the intended meaning.

Comment: note `im-config` is in package `im-config` and not installed by default on debian. so do `apt install im-config`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor oh, thanks, when I wrote this answer I was very bad at english. I'll edit it in a sec though, because there's a typo *(simpley)*, and also "didn't programmed with GUI" quite the opposite of "not a programmer" :) But thank you anyway!

Comment: FWIW, if i set those options, the compose key stops working entirely. That's on Fedora 32 with Cinnamon.

Comment: @TomAnderson I'm on Manjaro. When I tried to follow exactly these steps, it also happened to me that the compose key stopped working (I'm testing on firefox). Then, following this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fcitx#XIM
and messing around a bit, I found out that adding
`export GTK_IM_MODULE DEFAULT=xim`
and
`export QT_IM_MODULE  DEFAULT=xim`
to both `/etc/profile` and `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc/` did the job.