# How to list all currently available compose key combinations?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, compose-key

Is there some way to inspect the state of X to get exactly and only a list of compose key shortcuts and what they map to, either as literal keys, for example:

```
aa å
88 ∞
```

or as glyph names, for example:

```
aa Latin Small Letter A with ring above
88 Infinity
```

or, ideally, a combination.

I'm *not* using GNOME.

---

After reading the links in the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248031/3645) I ended up with the [following command](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/a6bf33f17d0fb28ce3ac5441f8a168dda7db639b/.bash_history#L662):

```
less "/usr/share/X11/locale/$(grep --max-count=1 "${LANG%.*}.UTF-8\$" /usr/share/X11/locale/locale.dir | cut --delimiter=/ --fields 1)/Compose"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work if Compose files are elsewhere (like in NixOS, where they are in `/nix/store/[omitted]-libX11-[omitted]/share/X11/locale/[omitted]/Compose`.

It also doesn't work if a fallback locale is used. My locale is "en_NZ.UTF-8". There is no `Compose` file for this locale, but still a bunch of compose keys are available. Presumably it falls back to another, unknown locale.

Finally, it doesn't take into account `$XCOMPOSEFILE`.

Answer (score 12):

Not exactly.  If you are talking about X alone, you can look at the compose tables.  However, some people want to know this about GNOME without making a distinction.

- [The Gtk Compose Table](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable) started off as ***`X`*** compose tables, but has diverged (as well as providing some new codes).  According to the documentation, that information is built into the program.
- For ***`X`***, as mentioned, that information is in the Compose tables as discussed in *[Where can I find the full list of Compose combinations for my locale?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34932/where-can-i-find-the-full-list-of-compose-combinations-for-my-locale)* and *[FULL LIST of Entering Special Characters with Compose Key?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/full-list-of-entering-special-characters-with-compose-key-922021/)*.

Comment: I wish there was a tool on X (or Wayland... however this does keyboard input, it's apparently "different") like WinCompose's "Show sequences".  I mean... X has that info.  Why is it not accessible?