# XCompose multiple characters: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, compose-key

In my `~/.XCompose`, I have this line:

```
<Multi_key> + <3> + <3> : "¯\_(ツ)_/¯" # Shrug.
```

Which sadly, does not do what I want. Since only the first characters of the shrug is used.

Can I have multiple characters based of one key combinations?

Comment: A compose sequence only inserts one character. You need a different tool.

Comment: @Gilles Any suggestion for another tool?

Comment: It works fine in xterm. It fails in qt apps.

Comment: @Sardathrion have you tried autokey?

Comment: @frabjous No, I have not. I shall give it a try.

Comment: Autokey fails with `(autokey-gtk:22991): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 08:02:07.587: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose sequences which outputs strings (as opposed to just boring characters) seem to work in some applications.  I’ve only tested a few.

It works in:

- gedit
- xterm

It doesn’t work in:

- firefox
- gnome-terminal

Also your mapping doesn’t work for me.  But it does if I remove the plus signs:

```
<Multi_key> <3> <3> : "¯\_(ツ)_/¯" # Shrug.
```

And you should escape the backwards slash:

```
<Multi_key> <3> <3> : "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯" # Shrug.
```

### Update 2021-10-30

I’ve ended up using compose sequences that output strings (rather than just single keysyms/characters) quite a lot.  I mostly use it for single words.

In my experience it works really well, i.e. it works on most contexts that I type things.

This emoji now works for me in all four applications that I originally tested.

My own strings don’t contain Katakana (`ツ`) so they might be easier to use in more settings (higher Unicode code points might be less supported?).

Some exceptions:

- Can’t use compose mappings to strings (or any compose mappings?) in the search prompt in CopyQ (clipboard manager)
- Might not work in popup dialogs or other secondary windows
- It works in Intellij but the string is ostensibly typed rapidly one character at a time, instead of just appearing right away like it does in most applications.  This has no functional downside

Comment: Of course, it works in things I do not use and does not in things I do. Typical! ☺Thank you.

Comment: I've tested right now, and those multi-char sequences definitely work on the browser (but seem to fail in Qt applications). Remember that `~/.XCompose` is read by libX11 only during a program startup, which means new processes will support new mappings, while old ones need to be relaunched. https://wiki.debian.org/XCompose

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia Good point.  Maybe Qt applications in general don’t work.

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166954/185805

Comment: Works for me in Firefox and gnome-terminal on Fedora 32. IBus 1.5.21 (Aug 23, 2019) had enhancements to the Compose key functionality. That might explain why it now works. https://desktopi18n.wordpress.com/2019/10/17/ibus-1-5-21-is-released/ I tested in both X11 and Wayland.

Comment: @RobinA.Meade Doesn't work for me in Firefox and gnome-terminal on Fedora 32! IBus 1.5.22. But then, i am using Cinnamon, could that be relevant?

Comment: @TomAnderson I successfully tested in the Cinnamon Spin of Fedora 32. The blog post I linked to says "you need to enable more than one IBus engine." I used **im-chooser >  Use IBus > Preferences** to add **Japanese - Kana Kanji** and then the above example of `33` becoming a shrug worked. I do see a warning printed in the console by `im-chooser` which says "GTK+ supports to output one char only." But it works anyway.

Comment: @RobinA.Meade Aha! I had missed that detail, and indeed, with that trick, it works! Thank you! I don't know Japanese, so i have picked Ancient Greek as my second engine, which is fine υντιλ ι αχτἰατε ιτ βψ μιστακε. I notice that now when i use the compose key, a special marker appears, an underlined square overlapping a circle. Clearly some more powerful sorcery is now at work. Right, off to set up compose sequences for all the alchemical symbols i've been missing ...