# A shrug ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ in awesome key bindings

Tags: awesome, xdotool

This is the code I currently have:

```
-- Silly shrug emoji.
awful.key({ modkey }, "F12",
    function ()
        awful.util.spawn("xdotool getactivewindow type '¯\\_(ツ)_/¯'", false)
    end,
    {description = "Silly shrug emoji", group = "awesome"})
```

Sadly, all it seems to do is to send the active window to the last tag. What am I doing wrong?

Note that the command line works just fine:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: This question follows https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511450/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP Why would that be relevant? Just curious…

Comment: When I try `xdotool getactivewindow type '-'` I get `XGetWindowProperty[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW] failed (code=1)` it doesn't look like xdotool is the most stable piece of software.